# Azure devops ios - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1)

Tags: ios, azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

Unfortunately, I have been stucked in this problem for a few days and I decided to share it with you. Thank you for reading.
In Azure-devops CI/CD for iOS application, I run a job and all the steps are executed successfully, but I do not know why the app is not transferred to the App Center.

In fact, all the steps are successful, but in the end I come across a Warning (the last screen shot) and I do not know if this is the problem or not.
Below are screenshots of different steps and I hope you can help me. Thank you in advance
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to deploy an iOS release to MS App Center from Devops and getting the same thing. My last release was on the 11th. May be an App Center problem or pipeline task issue

EDIT: It looks like I was missing a value for the build target's Version. Rebuilt the archive locally & this is what lead to a successful manual upload on the MS App Center distribute page after multiple failures there too

.xcodeproj -> Targets->General->Build